# Show that $\sup\{\|Av\|:v\in V{\mbox{ with }}\|v\|\leq 1\} =\sup\{\|Av\|:v\in V{\mbox{ with }}\|v\|=1\}$ directly.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Given two normed vector spaces $V$ and $W$ (over the same base field, either the real numbers $R$ or the complex numbers $C$), a linear map $A : V \rightarrow W$ is continuous if and only if there exists a real number $c$ such that

${\displaystyle \|Av\|\leq c\|v\|\quad {\mbox{ for all }}v\in V.} $

The definition above is extracted from [Wiki](http://Given%20two%20normed%20vector%20spaces%20V%20and%20W%20(over%20the%20same%20base%20field,%20either%20the%20real%20numbers%20R%20or%20the%20complex%20numbers%20C),%20a%20linear%20map%20A%20:%20V%20%E2%86%92%20W%20is%20continuous%20if%20and%20only%20if%20there%20exists%20a%20real%20number%20c%20such%20that%20%20%7B%5Cdisplaystyle%20%5C%7CAv%5C%7C%5Cleq%20c%5C%7Cv%5C%7C%5Cquad%20%7B%5Cmbox%7B%20for%20all%20%7D%7Dv%5Cin%20V.%7D%20%7B%5Cdisplaystyle%20%5C%7CAv%5C%7C%5Cleq%20c%5C%7Cv%5C%7C%5Cquad%20%7B%5Cmbox%7B%20for%20all%20%7D%7Dv%5Cin%20V.%7D).

In the same [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm#Equivalent_definitions), we have the following:

\begin{aligned}\|A\|_{{op}}&=\inf\{c\geq 0:\|Av\|\leq c\|v\|{\mbox{ for all }}v\in V\}\\&=\sup\{\|Av\|:v\in V{\mbox{ with }}\|v\|\leq 1\}\\&=\sup\{\|Av\|:v\in V{\mbox{ with }}\|v\|=1\}\\&=\sup \left\{{\frac  {\|Av\|}{\|v\|}}:v\in V{\mbox{ with }}v\neq 0\right\}.\end{aligned}

> Question: Show that $\sup\{\|Av\|:v\in V{\mbox{ with }}\|v\|\leq 1\}
>  =\sup\{\|Av\|:v\in V{\mbox{ with }}\|v\|=1\}$ directly.

Clearly we have $\sup\{\|Av\|:v\in V{\mbox{ with }}\|v\|\leq 1\} \geq \sup\{\|Av\|:v\in V{\mbox{ with }}\|v\|=1\}$.

However, I do not know how to prove the converse. All the proofs I found online involve showing the other definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, this equivalence only holds if $V\ne\{0\}$.

If $A=0$ there is nothing to prove. Let now $A\ne0$ then there is $v$ with $Av\ne0$.

Let $v\ne0$ with $\|v\|\le 1$ be given. Then
$$
\|Av\| = \|v\|\cdot \left\|A \frac v{\|v\|}\right\|\le \left\|A \frac v{\|v\|}\right\|,
$$
which shows the converse direction, as the zero vector will not contribute to the supremum if $A\ne0$.